# Revit API - Exception thrown: 'Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InternalException' in RevitAPI.dll - When trying to run button twice

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit, pyrevit

**Objective**

Hi All, I'm working on making a button in Revit that is meant to add a single viewport to a new sheet and then change the viewport to show a viewTitle instead of being empty or just a line

**Error**

When I run the button for the first time, everything works except the view title is not set to the loaded family although the view title "line" is showing. My error occurs when I run the button the second time.

This is the error I get when I try to run the button a second time:

```
Exception thrown: 'Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InternalException' in RevitAPI.dll
A managed exception was thrown by Revit or by one of its external applications.
```

The error occurs at this line :

```
Viewport newViewPort = Viewport.Create(doc, viewSheet.Id, duplicatedPlan2Copy, new XYZ(location.U, location.V, 0));
```

**Exploration**

From what I've researched, the button is trying to access an element that is already being accessed but if I'm changing the scale, I should be able to change the ViewTitle. See references at the bottom of this question

**here is some of my code** which is in the transaction

```
FamilySymbol firstSheet = colTitleBlocks.FirstElement() as FamilySymbol;
ViewSheet viewSheet = ViewSheet.Create(doc, firstSheet.Id);
UV location = new UV((viewSheet.Outline.Max.U - viewSheet.Outline.Min.U) / 2,
                                            (viewSheet.Outline.Max.V - viewSheet.Outline.Min.V) / 2);

ElementId duplicatedPlan2Copy = duplicatedPlan.Duplicate(ViewDuplicateOption.WithDetailing);
Viewport newViewPort = Viewport.Create(doc, viewSheet.Id, duplicatedPlan2Copy, new XYZ(location.U, location.V, 0));
```

**Findings**
I've found that if I remove this line from my code: 
`bool elementType = doc.GetElement(newViewPort.GetTypeId()).get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.VIEWPORT_ATTR_LABEL_TAG).Set(viewTitleIdCommand);`

It works and is able to create new sheets and place viewports with the view title line only repeatedly.

Any and all help is appreciated.
[This link here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/exception-thrown-autodesk-revit-exceptions-internalexception-in/td-p/9063244) shows how having 2 separate transaction commits solved the problem however I tried it and that didn't work. [this one shows something similar](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/aec/2012/08/deleting-a-collection-of-elementsfamilies-the-correct-approach.html)

[Here is a reference to my other related question regarding the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641220/revit-api-c-sharp-how-to-set-view-title-on-viewport?noredirect=1#comment109088040_61641220)

Comment: Not related to the question, I'd highly suggest formatting the question to be simple and to the point. Lots and lots of explanations really does not help the reader try to understand the issue. Identify where the problem area is, ask a clear question and provide working code examples.

Comment: I'll try reformatting and simplifying later tonight. Formatting stack overflow questions are not one of my strengths unfortunately.

Comment: @EhsanIran-Nejad, I've reformatted the question. Hopefully, it is more clear this time around. Let me know if it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I was initially trying to using the TitleView's elementId loaded in from my `LoadFamily` class that I had instead of finding the elementId through a Filtered Element Collector.

I'm not sure why that was throwing me an error but it was.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you explore and test your intended functionality manually through the user interface first. Once that is stable and optimised and works as expected, you can move over to automating the same steps programmatically through the Revit API. That will probably help you understand what the problem is in a much more efficient manner than struggling with the API, which just replicates the UI functionality.

Comment: In Revit the steps are, 1) `Load titleblock` -> 2) `load view title` -> 3) `duplicate view` -> 4) `place view on sheet` -> 5) `set scale` -> 6) `edit type` and change `Title` from `<none>` to `your view title you loaded ` -> 7) change `show title` from `When multiple viewports` to `yes`. Did I miss any steps? As mentioned in the question. It works continuously if i `set the view title` and then change it back to `<none>` and then hit the button and also I don't get an `Internal Exception` Error.